# PostgreSQL : Gin max fields size

Tags: postgresql, full-text-indexing, gwt-gin

I'm currently evaluating many FullText indexing solutions, and I'm playing with native postgres FT.

I'm trying to index my data using GIN indices. But there's a limitation in the field size, I encounter some errors saying "huge tuple" while inserting data

As far as I understand, it's directly related to the field size.
But this limitation is not written in any documentation I found, so does someone know this limitation, and if ther'es some way to change it ?

thanks

PS : I found this definition in postgresql source code :

    `((BLCKSZ - SizeOfPageHeaderData - \ MAXALIGN(sizeof(GinPageOpaqueData))) / 3 - sizeof(ItemIdData))`

and will try to use it if nobody has some quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

The ["12.11. Limitations"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-limitations.html) section in the docs probably is what are you looking for.

Comment: no in fact this is limitation for text search, not for the GIN kind of index, some data accepted using a GIST index are returning errors while trying to use a GIN index.

Comment: You mean that in both cases (GIN and GiST) the data is within the limits mentioned in the section I've linked to but you see errors when you choose to use a GIN index?